# Adding In and NotIn to System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, is it possible?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I am trying to create an `In` and `NotIn` Expression operation or essentially extend `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` to have the ability to check if the property value is in an array of list of property values but I don't know if it is even possible.

I was reading [this article](https://www.infoq.com/articles/expression-compiler) and it said "There is no way of performing a series of arbitrary operations". I don't know if creating those new operations is even possible or where to start. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

```
public static BinaryExpression MakeBinary(
  ExpressionType binaryType, 
  Expression left, 
  Expression right)
```

Comment: It would help to have an example of how you would expect to use this function and what you would expect it to output.

Comment: So you have an expression that gives you an object `foo`, an expression that gives you a property `Bar` on the type of `foo`, and an expression `values` that gives you an array of the type that `Bar` returns, and you want an expression that checks whether `values.Contains(foo.Bar);`? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, you are not misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just invoke the `Enumerable.Contains` method.

```
static Expression<Func<IEnumerable<string>, bool>> containsExpr = en => en.Contains(null);
static MethodInfo containsMethodInfo = ((MethodCallExpression)containsExpr.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();

public static Expression In(this Expression value, Expression arrayOfValues)
{
    return Expression.Call(containsMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(arrayOfValues.Type.GetElementType()),
            arrayOfValues, value);
}

public static Expression NotIn(this Expression value, Expression arrayOfValues)
{
    return Expression.Not(In(value, arrayOfValues));
}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
public class Foo { public int FooValue { get; set; } }

public void ExpressionInArray()
{
    var propertyReference = MemberExpression.Property(Expression.Constant(new Foo() { FooValue = 3 }), "FooValue");
    var validValues = Expression.Constant(new[] { 3, 4, 5 });
    var invalidValues = Expression.Constant(new[] { 6, 7, 8 });

    var expressionEvaluatingToTrue = propertyReference.In(validValues);
    var expressionEvaluatingToFalse = propertyReference.In(invalidValues);

    var expressionEvaluatingToTrue2 = propertyReference.NotIn(invalidValues);
    var expressionEvaluatingToFalse2 = propertyReference.NotIn(validValues);
}
```

That assumes that the type is an array and not just any old `IEnumerable<T>`. If you have to take any old `IEnumerable<T>`, you'd have to change `arrayOfValues.Type.GetElementType()` to something that takes `arrayOfValues.Type` and finds the appropriate `IEnumerable<T>` implementation on it and returns the generic parameter from that interface.